# Self updating application

Tags: package-management, rpm, packagekit

I'm writing an application (say, example_1.0.rpm) that is hosted externally (on example.com) and this app tries to update itself on every launch whenever new version is available.

My approach:

- Check for new version and download example_2.0.rpm)
- From application call "xdg-open example_2.0.rpm" and quit the application itself.

This approach work fine on Ubuntu 16.04 (with latest updates as of 6/7/2016) but Fedora 23 has issue mentioned below.

Questions:

- Is this the best way to do it or I can use some functionality of PackageKit?
- Fedora 23 (gnome-software 3.18.2) has an issue with above approach, whenever application calls "xdg-open example_2.0.rpm", gnome-software just shows the option to remove but not upgrade.

Comment: don't do this.  your users will hate you.  and justifiably so. At most, you should alert them that there's a new version available and then shut up about it.  **DO NOT FORCE OR NAG YOUR USERS TO UPGRADE**.  They may have very good reasons for NOT upgrading at this moment in time.

Comment: Thou shalt not [cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691545/self-updating-linux-application).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use PackageKit. It will work on both Ubuntu and Fedora.

Here is example how to use that:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-faq.html#session-methods

Comment: I looked at that but i don't see InstallLocalFile() method exposed by org.freedesktop.PackageKit service on fedora 23. But gnome-software is obviously handle xdg-open call but it is so buggy at this moment.